# Terraform: How to implement storage account management retention policy in Azure for All Containers but EXCLUDING one specific container/folder?

Tags: terraform, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I have followed the Terraform document where it mentions the code to enable storage retention policy including the container/folder - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_management_policy

But how do I enable storage retention policy for All containers but EXCLUDING one container folder. I do not want the data to get deleted under this specific container1/folder1.
I have used the Syntax prefix_match != ["container1/folder1", "container2/folder2"], But it is not working.

`````
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

      rule {
        name    = "rule2"
        enabled = true
        filters {
          prefix_match != ["container1/folder1", "container2/folder2"]
          blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
        }
        actions {
          base_blob {
            tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = 11
            tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 51
            delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = 101
          }
          snapshot {
            change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = 90
            change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = 23
            delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than    = 31
          }
          version {
            change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = 9
            change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = 90
            delete_after_days_since_creation                 = 3
          }
        }
       }
    }````

How do I enable storage retention policy for All containers but EXCLUDING one container folder. I do not want the data to get deleted under this specific container1/folder1.
I have used the Syntax prefix_match != ["container1/folder1", "container2/folder2"], But it is not working.
`````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-faq#the-blob-prefix-match-string-didn-t-apply-the-policy-to-the-expected-blobs) specifies it ignores `!=`.

> The prefix match considers only positive (=) logical comparisons. Negative (!=) logical comparisons are ignored.

I would recommend to either

- Put all the data you want to back up within the same container.
- If not possible, split the data you want to keep and not keep in two different storage account.